# How to insert Gravatar image into my email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, email, html-email, gravatar

**How can I insert my gravatar image in an email that I want to send out with Ruby on Rails?** According to Gravatar I need to insert the following code into my Ruby on Rails app:

```
image_src = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}"
```

Hash is essentially an encoded string for an email address. Hash is equal to:

```
hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(email_address)
```

I created a method called "gravatarurl", which you can see below:

```
def gravatarurl
  hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest("myemail@google.com")
  puts "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}"
end
```

---

Now, the code that I have in the mailer is:

```
def emailwithphoto
  @user1 = User.find(1)

  mail(to: "#{@user1.email}",
    from: "MNC@mydomain.com",
    subject: "Attempting to include image in this email")
end
```

In file app/views/image_mailer/emailwithphoto.rb I have the code:

```
<img alt="" src="<%= @user1.gravatarurl %>" class="mcnImage">
```

If I hard code my gravatar url into the file "emailwithphoto.rb" then I can see my gravatar photo, but I need the email to be dynamic.

*What am I missing or not seeing? Thank you in advance for your help!*

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code in method gravatarurl. I changed "put" and replaced it with "return. This is the new code for method gravatarurl:

```
def gravatarurl
  hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest("myemail@google.com")
  return "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}"
end
```

Now I can use the Gravatar image in emails.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `gravatarurl` in the `user` model and then call `@user1.gravatarurl` and not `@image1.gravatarurl`

Comment: Hello @Zepplock, I wrote the wrong code in my question. When I put "@user1.gravatarurl", the email did not send me the image of my Gravatar.